# How to parse a string with many dates into a List<DateTme>?

Tags: c#, json, list, datetime

I have a `string` that look like this:
`[12-20-2019 11:27:57, 12-20-2019 11:27:58, 12-20-2019 11:27:59]` each date is separate by `,` how can I parse it into a `List<DateTime>`?

My code is:

```
string datesListString = JObject.Parse(jsonContent)["datesList"].ToString();
ListDateTime> datesList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<DateTime>>(datesListString);
```

`DatesListString` is a field of a big JSON file that I need to deserialize.

Comment: You need to first split the string and obtaining a sequence of strings, then you need to map each string to an instance of DateTime by using the DateTime.Parse method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a question about the initial string: does it include square brackets or not ? It is really important to understand the exact string format (I mean whether or not it contains brackets and what is the separator character) in order to being able to split the string and parse the obtained substrings to instances of DateTime

Comment: yes it have brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string yourString = "[12-20-2019 11:27:57, 12-20-2019 11:27:58, 12-20-2019 11:27:59]";    
List<DateTime> dates = yourstring
    .Trim('[', ']')
    .Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss", null))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char' on ```.Split(", ")```

Comment: @andreauttini I've updated my answer; the overloaded version including `StringSplitOptions` is needed to split on string rather than char.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by combining [`string.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___) method and [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) from `System.Linq`

```cs
var dateString = "12-20-2019 11:27:57, 12-20-2019 11:27:58, 12-20-2019 11:27:59";
var result = dateString.Split(',').Select(d => DateTime.Parse(d, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

To skip the square braces you can simply use `Trim` method, like that

```cs
var dateString = "[12-20-2019 11:27:57, 12-20-2019 11:27:58, 12-20-2019 11:27:59]".Trim('[', ']');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try:

```
string dateTimes = "12-20-2019 11:27:57, 12-20-2019 11:27:58, 12-20-2019 11:27:59";
string[] splitDateTime = dateTimes.Split(',');
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
foreach (string dateTime in splitDateTime)
{
    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
      dates.Add(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string first, and then you can use `DateTime.Parse(str)` to get the DateTime object.

This demonstrates it:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "[12-20-2019 11:27:57, 12-20-2019 11:27:58, 12-20-2019 11:27:59]";
        str = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2);
        string[] parts = str.Split(',');

        foreach(var part in parts) {
            str = str.Trim();
            var date = DateTime.Parse(part);
            Console.WriteLine(date);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with DateTime.Parse, never never use it without culture or format!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is JSON:

```
var _str = @"[""12-20-2019 11:27:57"", ""12-20-2019 11:27:58"", ""12-20-2019   11:27:59""]";
```

So we can use `using Newtonsoft.Json;`:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(_str)
    .Select(s => DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

[Read mode about library Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)